# What are the possible ways to find $x$ in $Ax = b$ where $A$ is a $m \times m$ matrix and $b$ is a vector of size $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I know two methods to find $x$ in $Ax = b$:
$1.$ Since $A$ is a square matrix we find $A^{-1}$ then proceed to find $x$ as $A^{-1}b$.
$2.$ We can find row reduced echelon form of augmented matrix $A$ then use back substitution to find $x$.
What are the other ways to do so? Any way that we can use either in pure mathematics or in computation will be helpful.

For eg. if inverse for $A$ does not exist then also we can use maybe Pseudo inverse sometimes (don't know much about that).

Comment: You may use the LU or QR decomposition. If $A$ has a special structure (tridiagonal, triangular, Toeplitz...) there are special algorithms to solve the system. There are also iterative methods (conjugate gradient, Gauss-Seidel...). It's actually quite a broad question. Solving the linear system $Ax=b$ is probably the most studied problem in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: For invertible $A$ you can use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am familiar with cramer's rule, but I have to learn those advanced methods that @Jean-ClaudeArbaut mentioned.